# How to keep WCF Service Running after client Disconnect?

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight

I Have a Silverlight Application that calls a WCF Service (Full Duplex) wich is hosted in another web site (Both my creation, both i can change).

The system is working fine, but this WCF Service takes a long time to execute (sometimes more than 8 minutes).

I want the user to be able to close the application before the services finish and access the results later when he opens the application again. The same if the internet went out or the session expires.

My plan was to save all the data produced by the service into a table, and when the user enters the system again, I could check the contents on this table and show it to him.

The problem is that when a close the application (closing the browser, for instance), the Service keeps running for a while and then closes before completing. I know that because i was logging the progress in a DB Table. I close the browser when the service was at 30 %. It kept running untill 50 % then stopped.

So the question is : How can i keep the service Running on Server if the client disconnect for any reason?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question has anything to do with wcf. This is a situation where you need to run a method asynchronously.

So first create a class for your wcf client.

```
public class MyClient
{
    public void AsyncWcfCall(param1, param2)
    {
         Task.Run(() => DoCall(param1, param2));
    }

    private void DoCall(param1,param2)
    {
       using(var cleint = new MyWcfService())
       {
           //call the service, save to database etc.. and handle exceptions
       }
    }
}
```

Now from your ViewModel instantiate the above class and simply call AsyncWcfCall.

Comment: But the problem is when the client closes . In your example the DoCall method will still be on the client, and will be closed when the browser closes.